# Can We Implement Interceptor Using Redux RTK For Error Handling Or Other Option

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, endpoint, rtk-query

When API calls in React RTK query endpoints and receive response, but some times if the server throws an error, and API returns error - how to handle this in Axios its provide interceptor.

Can we implement interceptor in Redux RTK query or are there other alternatives to handle errors?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example how I have used axios interceptors with Redux-Toolkit Query with an axios base query function.

```js
import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosBaseQuery = () => {
  const instance = axios.create();

  // set common headers
  instance.defaults.headers.common.Accept = 'application/json';
  ...

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  return async (args, { dispatch, getState }, extraOptions) => {
    ...

    // Add response inceptor error handler (e.g. the second arg)
    instance.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {
      if ([401, 403].includes(error.response.status)) {
        dispatch(actions.snackActions.warning({
          message: 'Authentication token expired.',
          timeToHide: 99 * 1000,
        }));
        const logoutUserState = API.endpoints.logoutUser.select({ fixedCacheKey: 'logoutUser' })(getState());

        if (!logoutUserState.isLoading) {
          dispatch(API.endpoints.logoutUser.initiate(undefined, { fixedCacheKey: 'logoutUser' }));
          dispatch(replace('/'));
        }
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });

    // Run the query request using the axios instance
    try {
      const result = await instance({
        baseURL: /* your base URL here */,
        headers: {
          /* any dynamic runtime headers here */,
        },
        ...args,
      });
      return { data: result.data };
    } catch (axiosError) {
      const err = axiosError;
      return {
        error: {
          status: err.response?.status,
          data: err.response?.data || err.message,
        },
      };
    }
  };
};
```

```js
const API = createApi({
  baseQuery: axiosBaseQuery(),
  tagTypes: /* your API slice tags here */,
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    ...
  }),
});
```

In the above example the code is simply looking for 401/403 error response status codes to log the user out, but you can run any business logic necessary for your specific use case in the error handler.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should not reach for Axios (your browser already ships with fetch, and axios doesn't add a ton of functionality, but it does add a good bunch of bundle size - it's only really necessary if you target very legacy platforms), but stay with the normal `fetchBaseQuery`. Instead of doing interceptors, you would just "wrap" a new function around the function created by `fetchBaseQuery`.

```js
const origBaseQuery = fetchBaseQuery(options);
const myBaseQuery = (...args) => {
  // do things before if you want
  const result = origBaseQuery(...args)
  // do things after (like modifying result or returning something else) if you want
  // e.g.
  if ('error' in result) {
    console.log(result.error)
    // please don't do exactly this  - but you get the idea
    return { data: "how gracefully we handled this!" }
  }

  return result
}
```

The concept of "interceptors" is really overblown if you also just can wrap your baseQuery instead.